# How to call the functions of 2 other classes into another class

Tags: python, oop

Im new to Python OOP and i was hoping you could help me with my problem

Im asked to use the results of a function in 2 other classes in 3rd class to find a result
but im unsure on how to do that

```
class ADC():
    n_bit = np.array([2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], dtype=np.int64);
    def __init__(self):
        n_bit=self.n_bit

    @property
    def snr(self):
        n_bit=self.n_bit
        M=2**n_bit
        snr_lin=M**2
        return snr_lin

    @property
    def snr_db(self):
        snr_lin=self.snr
        snr_db=lin2db(snr_lin)
        return snr_db

    @property
    def m(self):
        M=2**n_bit
        return M

class BSC():
    fs_step = 2.75625e3
    error_probability = np.arange(1e-12, fs_step, 1)
    n_bit = np.array([2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], dtype=np.int64);
    def __init__(self):
        error_probability=self.error_probability
        n_bit=self.n_bit

    @property
    def snr_BSC(self):
        n_bit = self.n_bit
        M = 2 ** n_bit
        snr_lin_BSC=1/(4*self.error_probability)
        return snr_lin_BSC

    @property
    def snr_db(self):
        snr_lin_BSC = self.snr_BSC
        snr_db = lin2db(snr_lin_BSC)
        return snr_db

class PCM(ADC,BSC):
    def __init__(self,class_a,class_b):
        self.analog_bandwith=0;
        self.snr=class_a.snr;
        self.snr_BSC=class_b.snr_BSC #here it didnt show snr_BSC

    def snr_TOT():
        snr_tot=(1/class_a.snr + 1/class_b.snr_BSC)**(-1) #and here as well
        return snr_tot
    def Critical_Pe(self):
        P_e=1/(4*(class_a.m**2-1))
```

So what we are required to do is use the functions `snr` and `snr_BSC` from `class ADC` and `Class BSC` respectively into the `class PCM` to find the `snr_tot`

We need to put that in a graph along some other stuff but for now i would be satisfied just printing the result of `snr_tot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in your code you can do modify the PCM class,

you need to include the `super()` method. here the updated code -

```
class PCM(ADC, BSC):
    def __init__(self, class_a, class_b):
        super().__init__()
        self.analog_bandwith = 0
        self.class_a_snr = class_a.snr
        self.class_b_snr_BSC = class_b.snr_BSC

    def snr_TOT(self):
        snr_tot = (1 /self.class_a_snr+1 /self.class_b_snr_BSC)**(-1)
        return snr_tot

    def Critical_Pe(self):
        P_e = 1 /(4*(self.m**2-1))

adc_obj = ADC()  
bsc_obj = BSC()  
pcm_obj = PCM(adc,_obj, bsc_obj) 
print(pcm_obj.snr_TOT())
```

And yes you might need to rename the `self.snr` and `self.snr_BSC` in `PCM` class as these are `property` type and it might give you error like property values cannot be set.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. But there is also something else id like to ask. How can i now call the ```snr_TOT``` if i want to print the result?

Comment: For that, you have to create an instance of PCM class and then can call the function.

`adc_obj = ADC()`

`bsc_obj = BSC()`

`pcm_obj = PCM(adc,_obj, bsc_obj)`

`print(pcm_obj.snr_TOT())`